# How to remove sql records using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have this simple script that compare the two table and I'm just wondering how can I modify it so that it'll delete if there is a difference in `Hold_Inv` table.

So basically my `Temp_Hold_Inv` contain the latest data and I wanted to always in sync with my `Hold_Inv` table.

Let say a particular user is removed from `Temp_Hold_Inv` table but the data is already Existed in `Hold_inv` and `Daily_Proc` table then removed from those two table too after comparison.

Here I'm able to get the difference but not sure how to use $comparedResult to delete all the difference from `Hold_Inv` and `Daily_Proc` Table

```
$query2 = "
    SELECT 'Temp_Hold_Inv' AS SRC, T1.*
FROM (
      SELECT Hold, GID, Source FROM Temp_Hold_Inv
      EXCEPT
      SELECT Hold, GID, Source FROM Hold_Inv
      ) AS T1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Hold_Inv' AS SRC, T2.*
FROM (
      SELECT Hold, GID, Source FROM Hold_Inv
      EXCEPT
      SELECT Hold, GID, Source FROM Temp_Hold_Inv
      ) AS T2
;"


$compareResult = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query2 -ServerInstance $Server -Database $Database
```

Any help or suggestion will be really appreciated.

Comment: Are both tables on the same instance? If so, why not do the whole thing in T-SQL? Why return the data back to PowerShell?

Comment: Yes they are the same instance. This is like a small part of my entire PowerShell script so could you help me if there is away to do that just inside the sql query.

Comment: Why keep a copy of data in another a table? Depending on the reason, there might be better solutions.

Comment: @VonPryz Hi, basically we're getting the latest data in CSV file from different team everyday. What I'm trying to do is bulk insert CSV file to my Temp_Hold_Inv table and compare the two tables instead of comparing CSV file to my Hold_Inv table directly because it take so much time.

Comment: A `MERGE` statement might make sense, but you need to define your primary key to compare on, otherwise you can't match rows

Answer (score 0):

You need a `MERGE` statement, but you need to work out what is the primary key of the table in order to match rows up.

```
$query2 = "
MERGE Hold_Inv WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS t
USING Temp_Hold_Inv AS s
  ON t.SomePrimaryKey = s.SomePrimaryKey
WHEN MATCHED AND (
       t.Hold <> s.Hold
    OR t.Source <> s.Source)
  THEN UPDATE SET
    Hold   = s.Hold
    Source = s.Source
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
  THEN INSERT (Hold, GID, Source)
    VALUES (Hold, GID, Source)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
  THEN DELETE
-- you can get output like this
-- OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*
;"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query2 -ServerInstance $Server -Database $Database
```